# Why is selectedimage not defined?

Tags: python, machine-learning, streamlit

I have been trying to establish why, when I run the program it is saying that selected image is not defined, when it seems to be defined when I look at the code.

The error in question is:

```
NameError: name 'selectedimage' is not defined
```

I am using streamlit, an online GUI generator.

```
if st.sidebar.button("Identify"):
    selectedimage = "./AI_TESTING_DATA/" + imageselect
    selectedimage = Image.open(selectedimage).resize(IMAGE_SHAPE)

selectedimage = np.array(selectedimage) / 255.0

result = model.predict(selectedimage[np.newaxis, ...])

predicted_class = np.argmax(result[0], axis=-1)

labels_path = "./Product/labels.txt"
class_labels = np.array(open(labels_path).read().splitlines())

predicted_class_name = class_labels[predicted_class]

"It's a :" + predicted_class_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The if condition`if st.sidebar.button("Identify"):` is getting failed so `selectedimage` is not getting declared and so you are facing error in `selectedimage = np.array(selectedimage) / 255.0` line

If your `if condition` is right then check the value of `st.sidebar.button("Identify")`. It will be `False`

Answer (score 0):

If your if-clause evaluates to False, then `selectedimage` will be undefined. It looks like you probably want to move the entire rest of the logic under that if-clause, since it all depends on the button having been clicked:

```py
if st.sidebar.button("Identify"):
    selectedimage = "./AI_TESTING_DATA/" + imageselect
    selectedimage = Image.open(selectedimage).resize(IMAGE_SHAPE)

    selectedimage = np.array(selectedimage) / 255.0

    result = model.predict(selectedimage[np.newaxis, ...])

    predicted_class = np.argmax(result[0], axis=-1)

    labels_path = "./Product/labels.txt"
    class_labels = np.array(open(labels_path).read().splitlines())

    predicted_class_name = class_labels[predicted_class]

    "It's a :" + predicted_class_name
```